# Workaround LogbackValve Lack of Async Support

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, logback, zipkin

I'm trying to create a Zipkin 1.31.1 server using Spring Boot 1.3.5.RELEASE to build a fat executable JAR with with Tomcat 8.0.33 embedded in it.  This is failing with the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "<async-supported>true</async-supported>" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml. Also you must use a Servlet 3.0+ container
```

as described in [Spring Boot Enable Async Supported Like in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213050/spring-boot-enable-async-supported-like-in-web-xml) even with the suggested fix.

After setting breakpoints in the debugger, I found that the problem is the same as described in

[How to Make LogbackValve async Supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759795/how-to-make-logbackvalve-async-supported)

which wasn't answered and ultimately had the following improvement request created:

[ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve is not async-supported](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-827)

Does anyone have any recommendations how I can workaround this issue?  I need help either:

- Replacing LogBackValve in the pipeline with a wrapper that supports async behavior

OR

- Disabling LogbackValve and/or removing it from the pipeline and living without its benefits

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to disable the bean that was injecting LogbackAccess.  This resolved the issue so that Zipkin is now accepting requests.